# Исключающее "или" для трёх переменных

Tags: php, логика

Есть три переменные `x,y,z`. Когда одно из них `true`, остальные две - `false`. Как составить условие, чтобы проверялись сразу все три переменные исключающим "или" (`xor`)?
Для двух нормально всё работает.

**Дополнение из комментария**: Нужно выражение, которое возвращает `true` только тогда, когда **ровно одна** из переменных равна `true` и `false` во всех остальных случаях.

Comment: Что вы хотите в результате? `true` только когда __только одна__ переменная `true`?

Comment: Да, именно так!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно написать собственную функцию `xor` для нескольких элементов, которая возвращает `true` только когда **ровно один** из аргументов равен `true` и `false` во всех остальных случаях:

```
function multi_xor() {
    $res = false;

    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        if ($res && $arg) {
            return false;
        }

        $res = $res || $arg;
    }

    return $res;
}

var_dump(multi_xor(true, false, true)); // false
var_dump(multi_xor(true, true, true)); // false
var_dump(multi_xor(false, false, true)); // true
var_dump(multi_xor(true, false, false)); // true
```

Comment: Вот то, что мне нужно!